# Having issues posting with express and mongodb

Tags: forms, mongodb, express, npm, gulp

I am trying to post a form through express. For some reason when I am posting, it is posting about 4-8 times. It seems that when autocomplete is involved it using the keystrokes.

I am also using gulp and wanted to know how to post using express or if I should post separately in a javascript file.

*Code Example*

ADD USER FILE (which is included in my server file)-

```
var express  = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var form     = require('express-form');
var field    = form.field;

var User   = require('../models/user');
var router = express.Router({
  mergeParams: false
});

router.get('/user/add', function (req, res) {
  res.render('users/add', { 
    user: req.user,
    message: req.flash('addUserMessage') 
  });
});

router.post('/user/add', function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({ 'email' : req.body.email }, function (err, user) {
    if (err)
        res.redirect('/error');

    if (user) {
        req.flash('addUserMessage', 'This email exists already');
        res.redirect('/user/add');
    } else {
        var newUser = new User();

        newUser.email        = req.body.email;
        newUser.firstName    = req.body.firstName;
        newUser.lastName     = req.body.lastName;

        newUser.save(function(err) {
         if (err)
          throw err;
         req.flash('addUserMessage', 'Success');
         res.redirect('/user/add');
       });
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you have code to share? do you have an event handler hooked up to an event somewhere? gulp is a build system, not a way to post things.

Comment: thanks @ThrowsException - yes I have some code to share, I will post it above. I had a gulp boiler plate and they had the express server running as a gulp task. Would you recommend I have a separate file for my server?

Comment: What does your client side look like that is actually calling the post code? What event handlers do you have hooked up?